# Free-form tagging or classification authoring interface

Tags: xml, rdf, owl, xsd.exe, rdfa

I'm trying to create a front-end interface for the following syntax, so a user can work with the output while authoring the input unknowingly.

```
<tag=complete sentence|sentence about a female loving a male|love><tag=subject>She</tag> <tag=verb>loves</tag> <tag=object>him</tag>.</tag>
```

What the user should see:

```
She loves him.
```

Upon selecting/highlighting the entire sentence "She loves him.", there should be a side panel or some other interface which contains all of the tags for this tag-group, which as we can see in the source code contains "complete sentence" and "sentence about a female loving a male" and "love", delimited by | characters.

Upon selecting only "She", the interface should display only the tag for that tag-group, which from the source code is "subject".

Upon selecting only "loves" or "him", the respective tag-group elements should be shown.

Upon selecting only the "." period character, then nothing should be shown since by itself it doesn't have a tag-group.

Later, I could add the ability to highlight a single character, or a phrase, to create a new tag group, and have the user create structured content in this way without having to look at the messy syntax.

I have looked into RDF, OWL, XML, and other structured tools which have interfaces already, but here is the problem:
They have unneccesary complexity and jargon in their structure. They typically only allow you to tag one thing from a dictionary, rather than freeform tagging as shown above. One should only use a tool when it is the right tool, and the right tool for this hasn't been made yet. I'm trying to get started.

If anyone would help me out it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I’m missing something, but … do you have a *question*?

Comment: the question is "How to get started creating the front-end interface described above?"

Basically, how do you take source code like "<tag=complete sentence" for your own invented language and work with it in a front end layer as described above

Comment: @Gallaxhar Then the question is probably too broad: **"There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."** or an off-topic library request: **"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."**  (Bold text is close reasons.)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AIML](http://www.alicebot.org/aiml.html).

For you example above and simplistic NLP it is absolutely perfect.

For more sophisticated stuff where you want to model language formally and tie it into a knowledge base, look below:

http://site.nlp2rdf.org/